# How to install laravel/ui package on a hosted project

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel project hosted somewhere, and recently it has started giving me this error

```
RuntimeException: In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.
```

My question is how can I install ui package in a hosted project. I am using Filezilla to access my project.

Comment: You have to install laravel ui in your local and test after successful test you have to upload your hosted project. This is simple way for you

Comment: Heyy! my project was working fine until very recently, can you please check out the answer and the comments below, and suggest anything? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Auth:rotes in your project? If not comment that in your routes file. 
And if you are using these routes for authentication you have to run `composer require laravel/ui:^2.4` in your shell either on hosting or local

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm not really using Auth::routes and I tried commenting it out before, it gives following error `Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError: Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::register(): Failed opening required '/home/getnokri/se.getnokri.com/api/routes/admin.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in file /home/getnokri/se.getnokri.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteFileRegistrar.php on line 35`

Comment: i'm using the hosted project for just the api(s), and I dont need any routes/admin.php file, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: The page you are accessing maybe has some route which is from Auth::routes. You just have to remove these from your blade files

Comment: Can you tell me when this occur? Put your route which you are accessing.

Comment: I'm not using any blade files, not even the web.php, I'm trying to use an api with this route `https://se.getnokri.com/api/public/api/user-login`

Comment: And show me the route also (your api route)

Comment: Hey friend, just output some test line of json through your api and check if the error exist. put that in your controller method

Comment: Yes, I already have a controller that returns json output, but the Postman gives the same error, what's weird is that it was working perfectly fine until I tried to make some changes, which, apparently, I cant seem to recall (*sarcastic+sad smile*)

Comment: No before everything just return some dummy json data in your controller for testing

Comment: Nope, still the same error, anyways, I think I'll try to clone this project and host it once again, and THANK YOU SO MUCH for your time man! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good luck :) I can't debug the issue without the file access. That error is new for me

Answer (score 0):

> composer require laravel/ui
> try this bro